# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Freelancing Stack Exchange](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 9 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Competing offer from outside consultant](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/competing-offer-from-outside-consultant)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Should I debug application on customer server if it wasn't previously discussed as part of the job?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2749/should-i-debug-application-on-customer-server-if-it-wasnt-previously-discussed)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How do I communicate to a client that he's wasting time and money by using my services hourly vs. paying a monthly fee?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/how-do-i-communicate-to-a-client-that-hes-wasting-time-and-money-by-using-my-se)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [how intermediaries in freelancing work?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2818/how-intermediaries-in-freelancing-work)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How should I tell my side job that I quit my full-time job to work on their project full time?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/how-should-i-tell-my-side-job-that-i-quit-my-full-time-job-to-work-on-their-proj)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Retainer for Development Tasks](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2774/retainer-for-development-tasks)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the correct way to handle progressive billing, especially in the UK?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/what-is-the-correct-way-to-handle-progressive-billing-especially-in-the-uk)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Should I sell insurance services for web development projects?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2778/should-i-sell-insurance-services-for-web-development-projects)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Am I okay to use a client-provided laptop and work phone with IR35?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/am-i-okay-to-use-a-client-provided-laptop-and-work-phone-with-ir35)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---